# Is D-Link GO-SW-5E true switch?

Tags: networking, switch

Is it really a switch and not a marketing speak for a simple hub?

Just to clarify a switch transfers network packets to each port separately while a hub copies each packet to all ports.

Therefore (I don't know if it is easy or just a theoretical possibility) a user of one device connected to a hub can hack into NIC interface and sniff packets addressed to its neighbour.

Answer (score 1):

If it supports Gigabit Ethernet, it's a switch. (1000BASE-T uses a different kind of electric signalling, and wouldn't work with hubs *at all.*)

Even if it only supports 100 Mbps "Fast Ethernet", it's also 99% likely to be a switch, if it was made in the last 15 years.

You can search for the device's manual or technical specifications page, and see if it has any switch-specific features. Look for any of the following:

- "Full duplex"
- "MAC Address Learning"
- "Store-and-forward switching"
- "NWay auto-negotiation"

Hubs don't have any of those.

Note that switches are not free of security issues – although they learn which MAC addresses have recently used which ports, they can still be tricked in various ways (e.g. filling the MAC table with garbage).